# Issue Related to Read only DB file after installation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an Application in WinForms,
I have created SetupDevelopment project and then install an application using Setup.exe file
i have added MSAcceess db file into application folder file,
when i install an application the database file gets readonly. how can i make file writtable after installation?

I found some solution on internet and found that when i tried to install application in different path other than "C:\ProgramFile\"  and make application available to all user,it solves my Problem, but i want to install an application only in "C:\ProgramFile\" and want to available to only "Current user"
how can i achieve my Problem ?

Comment: How do you install your application?

Comment: I have created SetupDevelopment project and then install an application using Setup.exe file

Answer (score 1):

In modern Windows Operating System the folders 'Program Files' or 'Program Files (x86)' are read only for the common users. This choice has been done for security reasons and you cannot easily bypass this rule. The reccomended folders, to use just for the current user, are  `C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming` or `C:\users\username\AppData\Local` identified by the `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` or `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`. To this base folders add another subfolder identifying your application or company and install your database there.

If you want your database available to all users of the current PC, you could install it in the `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` that resolves to C:\programdata. (Again, adding a subfolder specific for your application or company)

Again, don't try to force the operating system to work against its rules. You will find yourself in trouble very often.